# CSS Target 2nd TD of 3rd TR in Table

Tags: css

I am trying to target the "Holders" value on [this page](https://etherscan.io/token/0x86fa049857e0209aa7d9e616f7eb3b3b78ecfdb0) (364578 addresses at time of writing this).

I have tried a few different css targets with no success:

```
.table tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(2)
```

as well as

```
#ContentPlaceHolder1_tr_valuepertoken.next('tr td:nth-child(2))
```

Here is a picture of the html structure [image]

How can I target the "Holders" value on this page?

Comment: what is your query returning? also, `tr` is not a direct child of `.table` but rather `tbody` ...

Comment: Your first selector is ok. I just tried in the console: `document.querySelectorAll('.table tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(2)')[0].textContent` and returns the value

Comment: `.table tbody tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(2)` should do the trick, but as @Ander pointed out your query is fine too. the issue with a query like that is that it will select every `td` element that is the 2nd child of every `tr` element that is the 3rd child of every `tbody` element that is the child of any element with the class `.table`

Comment: Wait, are you saying you try to change the _value_ of the td? Tds don't have values, only content. Other than that, your first selector is OK, as the others have said. Your second selector should read `#ContentPlaceHolder1_tr_valuepertoken + tr td:nth-child(2)` though; I think you were mixing metaphors there...

Comment: Please include enough HTML to reproduce the issue, as text, not as a picture of text.

Answer (score 1):

[image: here's the image]

Sorry I did not noticed the css tag for this question.

Use this for css:

```css
tr:nth-of-type(3) td:nth-of-type(2) { background: red; }
```

Answer (score -2):

To target that using css, you can add an id to that element.
This would look like:

```
<td id="id">Holders:
</td>
```

that way you can modify it using css.

```
#id {
  /*Your css*/
}
```

hope this helps!

Note: the `/*Your css*/` is just a comment. Remove it before you add your actual css.

Comment: sorry, not it is " you _can_ add an id to that element."

Answer (score -2):

You can use this way like a matrix:

```css
tr:nth-of-type(3) td:nth-of-type(2) { background: red; }
```

Comment: The question is tagged CSS, not jQuery.

Comment: You should [edit] your existing answer rather than adding a new one. Had you done so, I would have removed my downvote. Had you included the HTML and CSS in a Stack Snippet (icon looks like `<>` in the editor toolbar) rather than a picture, I might have even upvoted it. Now you just have a downvoted answer hanging about, which will contribute to an answer ban.